# Flutter: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'

Tags: flutter, dart

The code is:

[image]

There's a weird error saying that The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color' when I try to assign the color, what is going on here?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-Image. another thing are you using custom color extension/package for `context.theme`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Theme.of(context)` to get the color(and other property).

```dart
 color: color?? Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor.withOpacity(.2)
```

And try not to use `!` without null check.

Answer (score 0):

color datatype is Color?
please change the double datatype to Color?

```
final double color; 
to this 
final Color? color;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not assign double value to the color as you have defined color property of double data type.Change the data type of color to the `Color` like this:

```
final Color color;
```

if you wan to use hex color code you can do it like this

```
Color(0xffb74093)
```

in this the **b74093** is the hex code of the color.